# for loop to calculate average doesn't work as intended

Tags: javascript

I have a coding challenge in which I need to create some sort of an average calculator. As it's a beginner's course, the challenge is quite straightforward ( just input a bunch of variables and add them ). However I tried to use a for loop to make my life easier.

It keeps giving me the "NaN" answer when I console log it.

I don't really know what's wrong here. It seems relatively logical from my noob perspective. I tried putting the average var inside the for loop, but it would just average the 1st and 2nd, then move onto 2nd and 3rd, and then finally give me NaN again.

```
var johnTeam, mikeTeam;
var johnAverage,mikeAverage;

johnTeam = [89,120,103];
mikeTeam = [116,94,123];

function averageCalc(){
    var i;
    for (i in johnTeam){
        var j=i++;
    }
    var average=(johnTeam[i]+johnTeam[j])/3;
    console.log(average)
}
```

Expected result should be '104'.
Current result 'NaN'.

Comment: What exactly were you expecting `for (i in johnTeam){
        var j=i++;
    }` to do...?

Comment: There's a lot going on in your code that makes your question too broad for Stack Overflow. If you were to step through the code in the JavaScript console (F12 in any browser), then that should help you see what is going on at each step.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Now that I think about it... it seems really dumb. I was thinking " I can just make j become array[1] and array[2], to select the 2nd and 3rd terms, since array[i] is first. But now I realise it doesn't actually do that haha.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You just need to calculate the sum in the `loop` then outside you divide by the number of elements in you array.

Here's an updated version of your try :

```js
var johnTeam = [89, 120, 103],
  mikeTeam = [116, 94, 123],
  johnAverage = 0,
  mikeAverage = 0;

// added a parameter so you can send the team array you'll want to calculate its average.
function averageCalc(teamArray) {
  // stores the sum.
  var sum = 0;
  // loop and calculate the sum.
  // notice the teamArray[i] not only i.
  for (var i in teamArray) sum += teamArray[i];
  // calculate average based on the array length and logs it out.
  console.log(sum / teamArray.length);
}

// tests

averageCalc(johnTeam); // 104

averageCalc(mikeTeam); // 111
```

Comment: This could be cleaned up a little... I think your function would be more useful if it `return`s the result instead of logging it, and that would allow you to use your two currently unused variables as well.

Comment: i tried to be very simple as the OP said he's still learning (even we all still) and i tried to follow his attempt by just making the corrections. Thanks for your remark though.

Comment: If you want to continue logging the results from within the function, then I'd suggest at least removing the unused variables. (Didn't downvote by the way, nor do I plan to.)

Comment: The other answers are very valid as well, and everyone seems to know what they're talking about. However this one seems to be the easiest for me to follow through, thank you for making the corrections to my code. I am not used to JS syntax, I have just been exposed to some code here and there, without any practice.

Comment: You'd never use `for in` to loop an array, that's a very bad suggestion. Instead, one would use `for of` -> `for (let v of johnTeam) {
    console.log(v); // or sum += v; (in fact, you would use reduce instead of the loop...)
}` @emtee

Comment: @chrispbacon "in fact, you would use reduce instead of the loop..." yes, if you're an FP-oriented programmer. If you haven't learned what a callback is, and you've never heard the phrase "point-free", then a `for...of` loop or even a `for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++)` loop is just fine...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that's true - and it was just an addition. The point of my comment was that using `for in` is an "error".

Comment: You really should not use *for..in* to iterate over arrays. At the very least you should include a *hasOwnProperty* test as it's common to polyfill arrays for missing methods, and *for..in* may well iterate over those methods too.

Comment: I just want to make it simple for the OP, that's not my job to give courses.

Answer (score 1):

You'd never use [`for in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to loop an array, you usually don't use `i` after the loop. Also, `i` in your case is always only the last counter value. To get the sum of an array, you'd usually use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and to get the average you'll divide earlier result by [`length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)

```js
const johnTeam = [89,120,103];
const mikeTeam = [116,94,123];

const average = arr => arr.reduce( ( p, c ) => p + c, 0 ) / arr.length;

const johnAvg = average(johnTeam);
const mikeAvg = average(mikeTeam);

console.log(johnAvg);
console.log(mikeAvg);
```

Comment: I am sure its a very effective solution, however seems relatively complicated for me. I can understand the "const" however the average bit seems confusing, I dont get the reduce function ( as I googled for a brief 5 seconds it seems to reduce the size of the array or something ) but I don't get how it actually works in your example. If you could please explain step by step the "average" line that would be amazing.

Comment: @emtee Run the following in your browser's Developer Console and hopefully it should make more sense: `console.log('reduce:', [89,120,103].reduce((p, c) => { console.log({ p, c, 'p+c': p+c }); return p+c; }, 0));`

Comment: @emtee Patrick has added some links to the documentation that explains the functions in detail (as well as his comment does)... Don't use the answer you've marked as accepted - it's wrong

Answer (score 0):

Also consider using this :

```
var sumjohnTeam  = 0;
johnTeam.forEach(p => (sumjohnTeam  += p));
var avgjohnTeam= sumjohnTeam  /johnTeam.length;
```

Comment: This isn't an explanation, nor is it a particularly straight-forward approach for someone who doesn't even know how to write a for-loop yet.

Answer (score 0):

The arithmetic mean is computed by taking the sum of all the measurements and dividing by the total number of measurements. If you want to be a good statistician, `null`/`undefined` measurement counts toward `N`, the number of measurements, but not towards the sum of all measurements. That gives us this:

```
function mean( values ) {

  if (!values || !value.length) return undefined;

  let sum = 0;

  for ( let i  = 0 ; i < values.length ; ++i ) {
    const value = values[i];

    if (value == undefined || value == null) continue;

    sum += value ;

  }

  return sum / values.length ;
}
```

With that, it's easy:

```
const johnTeam    = [89,120,103];
const johnAverage = mean( johnTeam ) ;

const mikeTeam    = [116,94,123];
const mikeAverage = mean( mikeTeak ) ;
```